# How to use Array.prototype.map ()?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-hooks

Hi I have a quick question. I am working on a JavaScript Project and am needing to use.

const array = [1, 4, 9, 16];

const map = array.map(x => x  2);

console.log(map);

Error: missing ) after argument list

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to do, and you can always google the functions first before asking them: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: The problem is probably that you are missing an operand beteen the `x` and the `2` in your return statement

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to understand what you want to achieve with that code but if you want to resolve that issue you are missing the operator in between the x [] 2 --> insert the operator like (+,-,/,*) as per your need.

```
const array = [1, 4, 9, 16];

const map = array.map(x => x *2);

console.log(map);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an error here.

```
const map = array.map(x => x 2);
```

Change it as follow.

```
const map = array.map(x => x * x);
```

And don't use `map` as a variable name. It's confusing.